# Disable custom validator during page load

Tags: jsf-2, validation

I have a custom validator on a JSF page and i am using view param to set the value of `callbackUrl` intothe Backing Bean which is received in the URL.

For example,

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.jsf?callbackUrl=google.com
```

The JSF:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam id="callbackUrl" name="callbackUrl"
        value="#{userbean.callbackUrl}">
        <f:validator validatorId="com.me.something.CallbackUrlValidator" />
    </f:viewParam>
</f:metadata>
```

I have a custom validator that checks the URL whether this is valid. The custom validator executes once during page load and once during page submit. I would like only the validator to kick in only during page submit. Is there anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<f:validator>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/validator.html) tag has a `disabled` attribute for the very purpose.

To check whether the current request is a postback (a form submit), just check [`FacesContext#isPostback()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#isPostback%28%29).

```
<f:validator ... disabled="#{not facesContext.postback}" />
```